# What size are shimano MTB (wheel) hub ball bearings?

Tags: hub, bearings

I wish to replace the Ball bearings in my Shimano hubs. What is the standard sizing for MTB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rear hubs are generally quarter inch (9 per side, so 18) and front are generally 3/16 inch (10 per side, so 20). Obviously, if you're going to do this, order extras.

See [this crib sheet](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-metric.html) from Sheldon Brown.